# Setting up a Football Team

Tags: c++

hello I have problem with question My code work for all number but I dont know when I send it I get wrong answer here is the link of question any help could be great full  http://sharecode.ir/section/problemset/problem/2499

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        int pos[3];
        for(int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++)
        {
            cin>>pos[i];
        }
        if(pos[0] == 0 && pos[1] == 0 && pos[2] == 0)
            return 0;
        if(pos[0]<=26)
        {
            if(pos[1]<60)
            {
                cout<<"No positions"<<endl;
                continue;
            }
            if(pos[1]>=60 && pos[1]<70)
            {
                if(pos[2]<200)
                {
                    cout<<"No positions"<<endl;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout<<"Forward"<<endl;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if(pos[1]>=70 && pos[1]<80)
            {
                if(pos[2]<200)
                {
                    cout<<"No positions"<<endl;
                    continue;
                }
                if(pos[2]>=200 && pos[2]<500)
                {
                    cout<<"Forward"<<endl;
                    continue;
                }
                if(pos[2]>=500)
                {
                    cout<<"Mid-field Forward"<<endl;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if(pos[1]>=80)
            {
                if(pos[2]<200)
                {
                    cout<<"No positions"<<endl;
                    continue;
                }
                if(pos[2]>=200 && pos[2]<300)
                {
                    cout<<"Forward"<<endl;
                    continue;
                }
                if(pos[2]>=300 && pos[2]<500)
                {
                    cout<<"Forward Defense"<<endl;
                }
                if(pos[2]>=500)
                {
                    cout<<"Mid-field Forward Defense"<<endl;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        if(pos[0]>26 && pos[0]<=30)
        {
            if(pos[1]<80 && pos[1]>=70)
            {
                if(pos[2]>=500)
                {
                    cout<<"Mid-field"<<endl;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout<<"No positions"<<endl;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if(pos[1]>=80)
            {
                if(pos[2]<300)
                {
                    cout<<"No positions"<<endl;
                    continue;
                }
                if(pos[2]>=300 && pos[2]<500)
                {
                    cout<<"Defense"<<endl;
                    continue;
                }
                if(pos[2]>=500)
                {
                    cout<<"Mid-field Defense"<<endl;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        if(pos[0]>30 && pos[0]<=36)
        {
            if(pos[1]>=80 && pos[2]>=300)
            {
                    cout<<"Defense"<<endl;
                    continue;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"No positions"<<endl;
                continue;
            }
        }
        if(pos[0]>36)
        {
            cout<<"No positions"<<endl;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have to publish answers after reading all inputs. You are printing answers for each row. Try to read all rows at once and print results at once. ""The input terminates with “0 0 0”"'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside this `if` statement `if(pos[0]>26 && pos[0]<=30)` you have to add a condition when `pos[1] < 70` to print "No positions". An example test, which your program fails is `30 64 377`.

Now, even though you (almost) solved the problem in this way, I must say that your code is badly written. What I mean is that you have way too much conditions, corner case hangling and poor names for some variables. You can see [john's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20376459/2474231) for a (much much) better way in which you can implement this. However, his solution currently isn't perfect, so here is his code with all the errors removed:

```
int correct(int age, int weight, int strength) {
    if (age == 0 && weight == 0 && strength == 0)
        return 0;
    bool no_positions = true;
    if (age <= 30 && weight >= 70 && strength >= 500)
    {
        cout << "Mid-field";
        no_positions = false;
    }

    if (age <= 26 && weight >= 60 && strength >= 200)
    {
        if (!no_positions) cout << " ";
        cout << "Forward";
        no_positions = false;
    }

    if (age <= 36 && weight >= 80 && strength >= 300)
    {
        if (!no_positions) cout << " ";
        cout << "Defense";
        no_positions = false;
    }

    if (no_positions)
        cout << "No positions";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Please study carefully this solution for all the good practices that you are missing.

Comment: Good answer, what I should have written in the first place. Not sure the extra white space code is really necessary though.

Comment: Dear yasen thanks for your help your code help me to rewrite my code anyeway I thankfull for every thing

Answer (score -2):

Your logic is wrong (and too complicated). This is the easy way to do it.

```
while (1)
{
    cin >> age >> weight >> strength;
    if (age == 0 && weight == 0 && strength == 0)
        return 0;
    bool no_positions = true;
    if (age <= 30 && weight >= 70 && strength >= 500)
    {
       cout << "Mid-field ";
       no_positions = false;
    }
    if (age <= 26 && weight >= 60 && strength >= 200)
    {
       cout << "Forward ";
       no_positions = false;
    }
    if (age <= 36 && weight >= 80 && strength >= 300)
    {
       cout << "Defense ";
       no_positions = false;
    }
    if (no_positions)
       cout << "No positions";
    cout << endl;
}
```

When you write code try to *structure* the code as close as possible to the decription of the problem. You were trying too hard with all your different `if` and `continue` statements.

Comment: Please, be careful with those whitespaces, they will result in Wrong Answer (WA)! You also don't directly answer the question...

Comment: John:Sorry but your code is also wrong because I can be someone have to position but in your code all have just one please read the question and tell me a test case that my code does not work with that Thanks

Comment: Dear yasen my code output exactly fix the question output and dont have more whitespaces can you give me test case that my code dont work for that Tank so muach for your attention

Comment: @Danial It's not true than in my code everyone has only one position

Comment: @john Moreover, the code you are suggesting is wrong. You should be looking for min weight, and not max weight. (test age 32, weight 77, power 521). You have some typos as well.

Comment: @john In addition, you got the strengths amounts wrong.

Comment: in Test age 32, weight 77, power 521 the answer is no positions and my code work currectly

Comment: @yasen, OK typos fixed (hopefully).

Comment: @Danial Whatever errors there might be in my code the important point is that the structure (or design) of my code is better than what you have. It's closer to the problem description, it's easier to understand, above all it's simpler. All that logic you attempt is totally unnecessary. Have a look at my code (and yasen's code which is very similar), this is the correct approach.